# angular ng-grid replace field text

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to use this to replace text in a field but can't get it to work as I don't know where to put it. I put it outside of the $scope.gridOptions and then it is not defined:

```
gridOptions.columnDefs['field'] === 'summary'.split("PROFILE - ").join("");
```

Anyone able to help me to know how I can take the field identified and do the above for ng-grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the column index

```
$scope.columnDefs[0]['field'] === 'something';
```